# Input Value into input(username,password,email etc) and submit using javascript

Tags: javascript, web, autologin

I am working on extension and i need to put username/email and password into the fields and then submitted.

I have achieved this on lot of websites but I am having trouble getting it done on few site such as this "https://app.hubspot.com/login/".

I this when I place the value using javascript/Jquery's ".val()" method shows the value into the username input but the value attribute stay's blank checked by inspecting element.

I even tried putting the attribute using "setAttribute()" method of javascript.

I have managed to place the value into the textbox but when I click onto the username textbox the value get's blank.

And apart from the Username textbox. If i try to put value into the password field it doesn't get blank on focus or blur but placing the value using javascript doesn't make the login button clickable. But when i type using keyboard. Everything is normal as it expected to. The only problem is can's login in through javascript.

When i try to fire click event it does nothing.
When I try to fire submit directly it does nothing.
When I try to fire but finding closest form element and then submitting it it just refreshes.

I even try to simulate the input using this

```
            var item = jQuery("#username");
            jQuery(item).focus();
            jQuery(item).keydown();
            jQuery(item).keypress({which: 'A'.charCodeAt(0)});
            jQuery(item).keyup();
            jQuery(item).change();
            jQuery(item).blur();
```

I now I don't know what do I need to do in order to achieve this on these few sites.

**Please NOTE:- I have tried all this into browser console itself**

I really appreciate your time and help

Thank you very much everyone.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding For this site https://app.hubspot.com/login/ which is developed using React JS mutating the DOM directly by targeting the elements with javascript/Jquery will not help as react keeps a virtual dom which it updates on every change and finally compares with real dom and the applies the missing changes to real dom

In your case when you target any element through javascript/Jquery and change any value you are updating the real dom but those changes does not get updated in virtual dom hence your changes does not reflect when you start interacting with the site manually.

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply!
There is an application in the market which have successfully done this. The name of the application/extension is **Dashlane**.
It can successfully login. What can be the possible options/methods?